# I need to send a table in kdb+ and q as a properly formatted table and not as a a .doc, .csv, or .txt file

Tags: kdb

How can I send a table as a formatted table in kdb+ and q, without sending/saving them as a [.doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word), [.csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), or .txt file?

Example: .h.html tableName (it did not work for me)

Comment: Can you provide more information of what you're trying to do? As well as an example table and an expected output.

Comment: -->table from q query
q)tab
date       a b
--------------
2020.01.02 1 4
2020.01.02 2 5
2020.01.02 3 6


-->table to be seen on email
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics/numbers-table.png

Answer (score 3):

`.h.html` is not for that.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/doth/#hhtml-document

For `q` format print out you can use `.h.jx` to create strings

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/doth/#hjx-table

```
q)tab
date       a b
--------------
2020.01.02 1 4
2020.01.02 2 5
2020.01.02 3 6

q).h.jx[0;`tab]
"date       a b"
"--------------"
"2020.01.02 1 4"
"2020.01.02 2 5"
"2020.01.02 3 6"
```

Libraries such as `qmail` have some functions you can use to generate HTML tables:

https://github.com/t-martin/qmail#tables

Specifically `.mail.table`

Comment: -->table from q query
q)tab
date       a b
--------------
2020.01.02 1 4
2020.01.02 2 5
2020.01.02 3 6


-->table to be seen on email
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics/numbers-table.png