# Convert a KDB q query result table to a html table for email

Tags: html, email, kdb

I have a table resulting from a kdb q query and i want to convert it into a html table and send it the body of the email.
tab:([]A:1;B:2;C:3)

the above kdb q table of type 98h has to be converted into html table like this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

and send the above table in a email body using sendmail functionality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to send a table in kdb+ and q as a properly formatted table and not as a a .doc, .csv, or .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76413430/i-need-to-send-a-table-in-kdb-and-q-as-a-properly-formatted-table-and-not-as-a)

Comment: No it doesn't. This is sending the result of the q query table in the email body as properly formatted html table

Comment: Have you even looked at rianoc's suggestion of qmail? It generates html and uses sendmail.

Comment: I dont want to use any external libraries, tried to convert it into String using .Q.s and send it but i want it in the email body and not as an attachment

Comment: You will need to write your own version of qmail then as this is not natively supported by kdb

Answer (score 2):

This will work to create a string with an HTML table from a Q table, but it isn't particularly performant (it loops through each column in each row). Additional handling would also be needed for non-string list columns.

```
toHtmlTable: { [p_table]
    headerRow: .h.htc[`tr] raze .h.htc[`th;]'[string cols p_table];
    dataRows: raze {.h.htc[`tr;] raze[{.h.htc[`td; $[10h=type x; x; string x]] }'[value x]]}'[p_table];
    : .h.htc[`table; headerRow , dataRows];
 };

toFormattedHtmlTable: { [p_table]
    head: "<head> <style>  table, th, td {font-size:13pt; border:1px solid #D6D9DC; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left;} th, td {padding: 5px;} </style> </head>";
    headerRow: .h.htc[`tr] raze .h.htc[`th;]'[string cols p_table];
    dataRows: raze {.h.htc[`tr;] raze[{.h.htc[`td; $[10h=type x; x; string x]] }'[value x]]}'[p_table]; 
    : head ,  "<table style=\"width:100%\">" , headerRow , dataRows , "</table>";
 };


q){show x; show toHtmlTable x;} tab: ([]ColA:1 2 3; ColB:4 5 6; ColC:`a`b`c; ColD:("abc"; "def"; "ghi"))
ColA ColB ColC ColD
--------------------
1    4    a    "abc"
2    5    b    "def"
3    6    c    "ghi"
"<table><tr><th>ColA</th><th>ColB</th><th>ColC</th><th>ColD</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>a</td><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>b</td><td>def</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>c</td><td>ghi</td></tr></table>"

q){show x; show 100 cut toFormattedHtmlTable x;} tab: ([]ColA:1 2 3; ColB:4 5 6; ColC:`a`b`c; ColD:("abc"; "def"; "ghi"))
ColA ColB ColC ColD
--------------------
1    4    a    "abc"
2    5    b    "def"
3    6    c    "ghi"
"<head> <style>  table, th, td {font-size:13pt; border:1px solid #D6D9DC; border-collapse:collapse; t"
"ext-align:left;} th, td {padding: 5px;} </style> </head><table style=\"width:100%\"><tr><th>ColA</th><"
"th>ColB</th><th>ColC</th><th>ColD</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>a</td><td>abc</td></tr><tr><t"
"d>2</td><td>5</td><td>b</td><td>def</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>c</td><td>ghi</td></tr></ta"
"ble>"
```

A function to send mail could also be created like (note I don't have access to a box to test this right now...):

```
sendMail: { [p_subject; p_body; p_to]
    system"echo \"" , p_body , "\" | mail -s \"" , p_subject , "\" " , p_to;
    };
```

So you could do:

```
sendMail["my subject"; .h.htc[`html; toHtmlTable tab]; "foo@bar.com"]
```

Comment: The output in the email is not in a table format, it is as
<table><tr><th>ColA</th><th>ColB</th><th>ColC</th><th>ColD</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>a</td><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>b</td><td>def</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>c</td><td>ghi</td></tr></table>, 
but in a formatted html table

Comment: sorry for the above comment, it is not in a formatted html table @scottstein37

Comment: i assume by "formatted html table" you're referring to HTML/CSS styles, so I updated the answer to include a new toFormattedHtmlTable function